# Why does the Insertion Sort algorithm take up constant memory(if we disregard the input array)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I just learnt that an intrinsic property of Insertion Sort is that it takes up constant memory if the input array size is neglected. Why so?

Source:- Coursera- Algorithms 1, Princeton University.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm. Do at least minimal reading before asking question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are not declaring any auxillary data, other than some CONSTANT amount of variables (`i,j,temp`, maybe some more for invoking the function itself, still constants though), each of constant size. So we can bound the extra space we declare by a constant `C=4*maxSize{i,j,temp}`, and by definition of big O notaiton, it gives us `O(1)`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so after an in-depth study of Mergesort, I finally understood why insertion sorting an array takes up O(1) space. Basically, Insertion sort is an in-place algorithm wherein the need to create an auxiliary array( and the subsequent copying of data) is eliminated. The algorithm "overwrites" the initial array. On the other hand, Mergesort creates an auxiliary array and copies the data into it, thereby making the memory space it takes up directly proportional to N (for the last merge, size of aux array is equal to the initial array). Although the copy to aux array can be eliminated by improvising the merge algorithm but that would save time and not space.